# Kernel for my pc

Tags: kernel, iwlwifi, ubuntu-drivers

From past few weeks, I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel v5.3.13 and my wireless card is Intel Wireless AC-9560. There are many issues.
Which Ubuntu and kernel should I use?

Edit 1: Issues - Log files fill up due to errors thrown by iwlwifi.

Comment: use one of the latest kernels they are the ones most up to date,what kind of issues do you have with your pc.

Comment: The kernel you mention is EOL and unsupported now on your release. There are two kernels, the GA (general) kernel is 4.15, and HWE (hardware enablement) is now 5.4 for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  Use whichever works best for you.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks! Are 4.15 and 5.4 compatible with Intel Wireless-AC 9560?

Comment: @trondhansen My log files are full of errors due to iwlwifi. They fill up my memory and space and leave my computer unusable.

Comment: I don't know if they'll solve your issues, but your machine can have both installed & upgraded, and you use whichever best suits your needs (and both are supported so will increase your security over your current option). Also if logs fill up, there is often a reason that needs investigation, OR you can often lower the alert setting so fewer messages go to logs (*maybe not the safest option, but if you ignore logs now nothing lost*), OR make logs rotate & not grow in size beyond a limit (ie. set a `maxsize` so it's not wasting space) or other.

Comment: @guiverc I have tried setting the max size, but it doesn't work either,  but it also takes up ram and leaves my computer unusable until I reboot.

Comment: @guiverc Hey! Tried kernel v5.4, no issues till now. Thanks!